# Excel file format cannot be determined

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code;

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data_location = ""
desired_headings = ["DSP CODE", "TERRITORY", "PPD", "CURRENCY"]
df_total = pd.DataFrame(columns=desired_headings)

for file in os.listdir(data_location):
   df_file = pd.read_excel(data_location + file)
   selected_columns = df_file.loc[:, desired_headings]
   df_total = pd.concat([selected_columns, df_total], ignore_index=True)

df_total.to_csv("Final.xlsx")
```

Every time I run this I get 'Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.'.

Looking online, people have said to add engine='openpyxl'. However when I do that, I get the error file is not a zip file. Would anyone be able to help me?

Sorry, only just started to pick up Python again and only want to combine CSV files.

Comment: Excel and CSV are not synonymous. If you're reading a CSV file, use `.read_csv`.

Comment: `.to_csv("Final.xlsx")`.... also if you're writing an excel file, use `to_excel`.

Comment: Many Thanks @BigBen. Apologies for not picking this up initially and thank you for taking the time out to help me! This ran fine after

Comment: you should also install `openpyxl` module, not sure what you use for coding, on PyCharm it is quite easy, just write `import openpyxl` and if module is missing it will highlight for you and give you the option to install it